# Is there an easy way to separate themes on network?

Tags: multisite, themes

Assume we have a multisite network. All sites in the network are separated into groups by some option value. What I want to do is to separate network available themes to be available to specific groups.

For instance, I have `A-Z` themes installed. I want to activate `A-K` themes to group 1, `L-O` themes to group 2 and `P-Z` themes to group 3.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Categorising themes by folders in backend](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96361/categorising-themes-by-folders-in-backend)

Comment: @brasofilo I don't see an answer on my question in your link... I don't need to add custom column to themes list or theme actions, i need to find a way how to show different themes to different site owners... Or i missed something?

Comment: Oh, sorry, misread that. Retracting close vote.

Comment: Don't think somebody did ever build a plugin for that. Atleast it seems like it's possible to hide a theme from the list http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55081/hide-a-theme-on-list-of-themes-in-wp-admin-without-editing-core-files. So you can build this yourself.

Comment: Eugene, no follow up here? Or did you find another solution?

Comment: @brasofilo haven't found a solution yet. will try to implement it in the nearest future and publish a plugin for it.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to make you site categories slug match your [theme categories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96361/categorising-themes-by-folders-in-backend) folder names.

Here's how to filter themes: [Hide a theme on list of themes in wp-admin without editing core files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/55081/12615)

And then, supposing a site has the category `a-p` and the themes are stored in `themes/a-p/`, this will filter them out:

```
add_filter( 'all_themes', 'remove_themes_ms_wpse_117537' );

function remove_themes_ms_wpse_117537( $themes )
{
    if( 'site-themes-network' != get_current_screen()->id )
        return $themes;

    $site_cat = get_blog_option( absint( $_GET['id'] ), 'site_category' );
    if( $site_cat )
    {
        # Unset themes not in the folder /themes/$site_cat/
        foreach( $themes as $key => $theme )
        {
            if( strpos( $key, "$site_cat/" ) === false )
                unset($themes[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $themes;
}
```